# Google Analytics Timing posting in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics

I'm implementing Google Analytics for my ios project in Swift. I'm quite new to Swift and complete noobie in Objective-C. I'd like to track for how long users are using my app. However I cant get the following piece of code translated into Swift. Could someone post a code example, pretty please?

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createTimingWithCategory:@"resources"                      // Timing category (required)
                                                          interval:@((NSUInteger)(loadTime * 1000))   // Timing interval (required)
                                                              name:@"high scores"                     // Timing name
                                                             label:nil] build]];                      // Timing label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got it. I was just being blind. Here's the Swiftified version:

```
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createTimingWithCategory( "resources", interval: timer?.duration, name: "highscores", label: nil).build())
```